# Using 'less' to leave text on screen for small files

Tags: shell, less, pager

I'm pretty sure seeing this customization of the less command on some colleague system long ago, in order to imitate 'more'. What I want:

- If the file is short (less that one screen long), it should behave like cat: it shows the content of the file and exits.
- If the file is longer than one screen, it should behave as usual, waiting for user input and clearing its screen on exit and leaving the previous commands on the screen.

I've tried experimenting with less -FX, but it leaves tons of stuff on the screen for large files.

Comment: Have you tried with just `-F`? `-X` seems to do skip terminal initialization, so maybe that's why it leaves the screen garbled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Paste that on your terminal (or put it on bashrc):**

```
less_cat(){
     [ "$(wc -l <"$1")" -ge "$LINES" ] && less "$1" || less -FX "$1"
}
```

**Now you should be able to execute:**

```
less_cat /etc/fstab
less_cat /var/log/messages
```

And it will do exactly what you want.

**NOTE:** This solution is compatible with BASH/ZSH(see the comments)

Good lucky!

Comment: Not all shells set `$LINES`. `dash` or `yash` don't for instance.

Comment: Right i referenced your comment.

Comment: You may still want to use `less -X` instead of `cat` for short inputs for its ability to render unprintable characters in a useful way.

Comment: Is cat -v usefully too?

Comment: It's a matter of taste. But compare `printf 'a\200b' | less -FX` with `printf 'a\200b' |  cat -v`

Comment: Very nice example. Thank you. I think you're right, i am changing cat to less -FX, as the output must be similar for all the cases.

Comment: I would use a `if` statement instead of `a && b || c` here because if `b` returns with a non-zero exit status, `c` would be run.

Comment: Sorry if i have a bad english. Now i see that it is a honor to receive tips directly from you. Are you the one that discovered the shell shock vulnerability isnt? Now i see. :-O  :-O. You're just the hacker that have a button to destroy the world in a second, but rather than that you prefer to help us. Thank you for saying something for me i will never forget that! Believe me i think this is better than getting a tip from Linus Torvalds.

Comment: Thanks :-). Yes, [that would be me](/q/162287)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to keep the alternate screen switching behaviour for large files, and turn the -X switch on only for small files that fit on single screen and don't need scrolling.

That is now the default behavior in version 530 of `less`; quoting from the `NEWS` file from its [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/less/less-530.tar.gz):

> Major changes between less versions 487 and 530
>
> - Don't output terminal init sequence if using `-F` and file fits on one screen.

Unfortunately, as of 2019, some distros like Debian 10 still use older versions of `less`, so if you don't want to build it from [sources](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/less/less-530.tar.gz), the only solution is to use a wrapper.

Here is an example of such a wrapper. Its known limitations are that **a)** the `:n` and `:p` (next/previous file) commands in `less` don't work -- all the files from the command line are concatenated in a single stream, and **b)** It isn't able to cope with null bytes in input, unless `/usr/bin/awk` is actually `gawk` (GNU Awk) or Thomas Dickey's [mawk](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/).

```c
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { "tput lines" | getline max; max -= 2 }
{ l[NR]=$0 }
NR>=max {
        for(i = 1; i <= NR; i++) print l[i] | "less";
        while(getline > 0) print | "less";
}
END { if (NR < max) for(i = 1; i <= NR; i++) print l[i] | "less -FX" }
```

Comment: Note that @ThomasDickey's `mawk` also supports NUL bytes.

Comment: Not the mawk installed on my system (debian stretch)

    $ printf "a\0b" | gawk '{print}'
    ab
    $ printf "a\0b" | mawk '{print}'
    a

Comment: Yes, Debian still uses the ancient one from 1996, not @ThomasDickey's one.

Comment: At the time of writing, less 551-1~bpo10+1 is in buster-backports. https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way around that.

Either you let `less` use the alternate screen to leave the original one pristine or you don't (use `-X`).

You can't really expect `less` to restore the screen as it was and start using the alternate screen after it has read a full page.

We'd need somehow to wait until at least one page or eof has been read before starting `less` in the right mode and send the data. Something like:

```
page_stdin() {
  awk -v l="${LINES:=$(tput lines)}" '
    cmd {print | cmd; next}
    {lines = lines $0 ORS}
    NR == l {cmd = "less"; printf "%s", lines | cmd}
    END {if (!cmd) printf "%s", lines | "less -FX"}'
}
mypager() {
  if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    page_stdin
  else
    for file do page_stdin < "$file"; done
  fi
}
```

(with GNU `awk`, you can replace `ORS` with `RT` to not add a trailing newline if it wasn't there in the first place).

But that means that you won't start seeing the output of the piped command in `cmd | mypager` until there's a full page worth of it or it finished outputting. (try for instance `seq 200 | pv -qL40 | mypager` compared to `seq 200 | pv -qL40 | less`).

Note that it assumes you don't use things like `LESS=-s` and would be fooled by lines larger than the screen unless you have `LESS=-S`.